# How to lock windows 10 using c#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10

I'm trying to create a security application and I need to prevent the user to use windows 10 (lock) and only use my application by writing a password to unlock it, is there a way to do that?

**note: i dont want to use rundll32.exe to logout from the system**

`Process.Start(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe", "user32.dll,LockWorkStation");`

Comment: ‘freezes’ is likely not the correct word. Anyway, searching for GINA and “replace windows login” or “locked screensaver” might yield interesting reads.

Comment: What about Lock the PC by emulationg `Win+L` press, or something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Hexalon/b535d1afa578e9c476ab)

Comment: Indeed: you want to lock the system, freezing is for bad software or system crashes.

Comment: I just want it to lock the system without using Win+L, and use my application only

Comment: You want to do like system software and antivirus or UAC that block the system to show an advert by blocking all others software, isn't it ?

Comment: yes how to do that ?

Comment: Are you trying to override the lock screen functionality on Windows 10?  So, instead of Windows prompting for a password your program does that instead?

Comment: Found that and I can't set duplicate again: [UAC-style elevated prompt (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807761/uac-style-elevated-prompt) & [UAC prompt elevation - how does it work? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808237/uac-prompt-elevation-how-does-it-work)

Comment: My question to you is why?  You can install your own "Credential Provider" (the newer, more flexible replacement for GINA).  The Windows Lock screen does a lot for you (switching desktops, providing access to other security features, etc.).  Why do you think you want to do this.

Comment: It sounds more like you're wanting a [kiosk application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-methods)?